# Why does Prolog use =< Rather than <= like most languages?

Tags: syntax, prolog, operators, conventions

In my programming languages class we were running the program below:

```
range(X,Y,Z) :- X>=Y,X<=Z
```

This would not compile and after a short google search we discovered that prolog uses the =< opporator rather than <= like most other languages we have learned about.

Does anyone have any insight on why prolog does this? Is there a reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, there is a very good reason: `<=` looks like an **arrow**, and since Prolog is also often used for logical proofs, this is "reserved" to accomodate such uses when they are needed, denoting implication from right to left.

By the way, `(=<)/2` is quite low-level. Better use **constraints** to make your programs more general and easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I will accept in 4 minutes when it allows me to.

Comment: Great question by the way!

Comment: There is a simple way to remember why it is `=<` and not `=>`: Imagine you move your hand  from left-to-right along the symbol: With `=>` you get hurt, while `=<` is so smooth! Just like `>=`. Kind of.

Comment: With `=>` it first is so smooth, and then you get hurt; with `>=` it first hurts massively, and then gets so smooth, and `=<` is always so smooth.

Comment: I get the point, but do you have any reference for what you claim? (I am not in any doubt, just curious)

Comment: I learned this from [Ulrich Neumerkel](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/) in one of his lectures. I am not aware of a written reference for this. In fact, most interesting things about Prolog are not (yet) written down in my view. If it is any consolation, I find Ulrich's word more reliable than written references in any case.